# Using Multiple tags to run playwright tests in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, playwright, playwright-java

I have a large number of tests, all tagged with relevant tags.  If I want to run a number of different tags in the same run, locally, I use

```
npx playwright test -g 'tag1 | tag2 | tag3'
```

and that works and runs all tests tagged with tag1, tag2, or tag3.

in Gitlab, I'm storing the "tags" in a CI/CD variable called  Tags.  so the command I have setup in my gitlab-ci.yml file is

```
npx playwright test -g $Tags
```

It picks up the tags properly, but it does not run the proper tests.  Depending on how I format the variable

```
tag1|tag2|tag3
```

or

```
'tag1|tag2|tag3'
```

or

```
'tag1\|tag2\|tag3'
```

or any number of other variations, it either finds no tests, or just runs all the tests ignoring the tags entirely.

What's the magic configuration I need to use for this to work properly?

Klendathu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,  so after an afternoon trying too many iterations,  I found that this finally worked:

```bash
npx playwright test -g $Tag
```

Where the variable $Tag was a NON-quoted string of tags separated by a pipe symbol.

```
tag1|tag2|tag3
```

If I used

```bash
npx playwright test --grep $Tag
```

That would fail.  Not sure why it didn't like the full --grep command, but it just didn't work.  Having the single quotes around the string of tags worked just fine locally, but it choked on it in Gitlab.